# When trying to blit text message onto pygame, function only runs once

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I've written a simple RPG battle system. I want whatever is being printed to appear in a black text box on a pygame window. I've done that and written a function called TEXT(X) to display text on 3 different lines, but dispite me calling it after every print command it only runs once and displays only the first message.
If you run the program and compare it to the command prompt you'll know what I mean.

```
from pygame import *
    from userInterface import Title, Dead
WIN_WIDTH = 640
WIN_HEIGHT = 400
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)
DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0

init()
screen = display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
saveState = False

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GRAY = (30, 30, 30)
FONT = font.SysFont("Courier New", 15)



heroHP = 1000

hero={'name' : 'Hero',
      'height':4,
      'lvl': 1,
      'xp' : 0,
      'reward' : 0,
      'lvlNext':25,
      'stats': {'str' : 12, # strength
                'dex' : 4, # dexterity
                'int' : 15, # intelligence
                'hp'  : heroHP, # health
                'atk' : [250,350]}} # range of attack values


boss1={'name' : 'Imp',
       'xp' : 0,
       'lvlNext':25,
       'reward' : 25,
       'stats': {'hp'  :400,
                'atk' : [300,350]}}


ONE = None
TWO = None
THREE = None

def TEXT(X):
    global ONE, TWO, THREE
    if ONE == None:
        ONE = X
    elif ONE == X and TWO == None:
        TWO = X
    elif ONE and TWO and THREE == None:
        THREE = X
    elif ONE and TWO and THREE:
        ONE = None
        TWO = None
        THREE = None

def level(char): # level up system
    #nStr, nDex, nInt=0,0,0
    while char['xp'] >= char['lvlNext']:
        char['lvl']+=1
        char['xp']=char['xp'] - char['lvlNext']
        char['lvlNext'] = round(char['lvlNext']*1.5)
        nStr=0.5*char['stats']['str']+1
        nDex=0.5*char['stats']['dex']+1
        nInt=0.5*char['stats']['int']+1
        print(f'{char["name"]} levelled up to level {char["lvl"]}!') # current level
        TEXT(f'{char["name"]} levelled up to level {char["lvl"]}!') # current level

        print(f'( INT {round((char["stats"]["int"] + nInt))} - STR {round(char["stats"]["str"] + nStr)} - DEX {round(char["stats"]["dex"] + nDex)} )') # print new stats
        TEXT(f'( INT {round((char["stats"]["int"] + nInt))} - STR {round(char["stats"]["str"] + nStr)} - DEX {round(char["stats"]["dex"] + nDex)} )') # print new statsm


        char['stats']['str'] += nStr
        char['stats']['dex'] += nDex
        char['stats']['int'] += nInt

from random import randint

def takeDmg(attacker, defender): # damage alorithm
    dmg = randint(attacker['stats']['atk'][0], attacker['stats']['atk'][1])
    defender['stats']['hp'] = defender['stats']['hp'] - dmg
    print(f'{defender["name"]} takes {dmg} damage!')
    TEXT(f'{defender["name"]} takes {dmg} damage!')

    if defender['stats']['hp'] <= 0:
            print(f'{defender["name"]} has been slain...')
            TEXT(f'{defender["name"]} has been slain...')

            attacker['xp'] += defender['reward']
            level(attacker)
            if defender==hero:
                #Dead()
                input("Press ENTER to exit")
            else:
                hero['stats']['hp']=heroHP
                #Title()
                input("Press ENTER to exit")


def Battle(player, enemy):
    global ONE, TWO, THREE
    mouse.set_visible(1)
    clock = time.Clock()
    YES = Rect(100, 100, 50, 50)
    NO = Rect(500, 100, 50, 50)
    Text = Rect(70, 300, 500, 60)

    #while ((enemy['stats']['hp']) > 0):
    while True:
        for e in event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                exit("Quit") # if X is pressed, exit program
            elif e.type == KEYDOWN:
                if e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    exit()
            elif e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                # 1 is the left mouse button, 2 is middle, 3 is right.
                if e.button == 1:
                    # `event.pos` is the mouse position.
                    if YES.collidepoint(e.pos):
                        takeDmg(player, enemy)
                        print(f'{enemy["name"]} takes the opportunity to attack!')
                        TEXT(f'{enemy["name"]} takes the opportunity to attack!')

                        takeDmg(enemy, player)
                    elif NO.collidepoint(e.pos):
                        print(f'{enemy["name"]} takes the opportunity to attack!')
                        TEXT(f'{enemy["name"]} takes the opportunity to attack!')

                        takeDmg(enemy, player)


        screen.fill(WHITE)
        draw.rect(screen, BLACK, YES)
        draw.rect(screen, BLACK, NO)
        draw.rect(screen, GRAY, Text)



        YES_surf = FONT.render(("YES"), True, WHITE)
        NO_surf = FONT.render(("NO"), True, WHITE)
        Text1_surf = FONT.render(ONE, True, WHITE)
        Text2_surf = FONT.render(TWO, True, WHITE)
        Text3_surf = FONT.render(THREE, True, WHITE)


        screen.blit(YES_surf, YES)
        screen.blit(NO_surf, NO)
        screen.blit(Text1_surf, (80, 305))
        screen.blit(Text2_surf, (80, 320))
        screen.blit(Text3_surf, (80, 335))




        display.update()

        clock.tick(60)

Battle(hero, boss1)
```

Comment: Your `TEXT` function doesn't do anything other than setting global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small change made it work for me:

```
def TEXT(X):
    global ONE, TWO, THREE;
    if ONE == None:
        ONE = X
    elif ONE and TWO == None: # "ONE == X" changed to "ONE"
        TWO = X
    elif ONE and TWO and THREE == None:
        THREE = X
    elif ONE and TWO and THREE:
        ONE = None
        TWO = None
        THREE = None
```

<strike>I guess you can't compare strings with `==`. You **could** probably compare them with somethin like "equals". I know that in Java `==` operator would compare addresses, that may not be the same when having two "equal" strings.</strike>

Edit: But even if that's true, the second call of "TEXT" would need to get the same parameter value to work with your code... You are comparing ONE to X.

```
TEXT("A");

TEXT("B");
```

wont work then.

I tested (your code) again with:

```
TEXT("A");
TEXT("A");
TEXT("C");
```

And it works.

Comment: In python you can compare strings with equal. Python checks equality, unlike Java which checks identity.

Comment: Also, `//` is integer division in python. A comment is written after `#`.

Comment: thanks, I'll change my example (typed the comment on SO)